Need help parsing this sentence involving く-Form and nominalization
I bumped into this sentence in a blog:

白川漢字学説には形声の説明原理がなく会意的に説くのが特徴である.

At first I translated it as:

Shirakawa's theory doesn't have a principle for explaining phono-semantic characters, and is characterized by explaining characters as compound ideographs.

But then I suddenly wondered if it could also be:

Shirakawa's theory is characterized by not having a principle for explaining phono-semantic characters and by explaining them as compound ideographs".

Don't know if it's the right way to put it, but my question would be if なく is "inside" or "outside" the chunk of ...説くの.
The general sense doesn't change much, but I think they are different sentences. I haven't find anything online on how nominalizers act in a situation like this. Any help will be appreciated.

I think this sentence can be split into two parts like this.

{{白川漢字学説には形声の説明原理がなく}{会意的に説くのが特徴である}}. (A)

Now, there are several other possiblities of syntactic scoping (or in other words, other parse trees). One might be:

{{{白川漢字学説には形声の説明原理がなく}{会意的に説く}}のが特徴である}. (B)

While this is not impossible, it seems awkward. Xが特徴である has a hidden gap in it - XがYの特徴である. In A, the same gap is there and it's expected to be filled by something from the previous clause. In B, there is no previous clause - you need to go into one of its subclauses to retrieve 白川漢字学説. I think this makes it awkward, and a less preferred interpretation.
Further down the list of possibilities, there might be:

{白川漢字学説には{{形声の説明原理がなく}{会意的に説く}}のが特徴である}. (C)

However, this assumes the composition ……には……が特徴である which does not sit well to me. It needs to be ……は……が特徴である or ……には……（という）特徴がある. C seems more unnatural than B, if not ungrammatical.
The context can change preferences. The above is based solely on the given one sentence.
Lastly, I don't think there is something specific about nominalization here. Negation at the end of a sentence with two or more clauses can cause similar syntactic ambiguity.

Would a parsing like this {白川漢字学説には{{形声の説明原理がなく}{会意的に説く}}のが特徴である} make any sense? Also, would a sentence like 白川漢字学説には会意的に説くのが特徴である still be awkard/incomplete?

__には__が特徴である does not sit well to me. It needs to be __は__が特徴である or __には__という特徴がある.

Had it been 白川漢字学説は形声の説明原理がなく会意的に説くのが特徴である (or the other construction above), would the ambiguity in parsing be more marked? Considering that, is 形声の説明原理がなく会意的に説くのが白川漢字学説の特徴である the best way to convey the specific meaning of {{形声の説明原理がなく}{会意的に説く}}の?

In that case, C would be much higher, might be the top, among the possibilities. I don't know if that makes it more ambiguous or not.

I would conclude by saying that the answer to my second question is no, since using は in place of には is already an option that can be used and significantly increase the chances to be understood as C. Correct me if I'm wrong.
